# NameSpace Issue in JointJS version 3

Tags: javascript, namespaces, jointjs

I am trying to convert a legacy app from JointJS v2.2.1 to v3.0.2.  I’m hitting an error others have found:

> Uncaught Error: dia.ElementView: markup required. (joint.min.js:8)

A helpful person said: “Please note you need to be careful with the cellViewNamespace for the dia.Paper and cellNamespace option for the dia.Graph in this setup.  Running this snippet is a quick check you've set up the namespaces correctly:

```
const cells = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());
graph.clear();
graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(cells));
```

”

Can anyone offer additional help?  I don’t know enough about JointJS to resolve this issue and I don’t really understand the code snippet.

Answer (score 9):

If there is no `joint` variable in the global environment, you need to pass the shapes namespace explicitly to the graph (for models) and the paper (for views).

If you do not mind adding `joint` reference to the `window` object see @duanbw [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250486/2921495).

**Built-in shapes**

```js
import { shapes, dia } from 'jointjs'

const graph = new dia.Graph({ /* attributes of the graph */ }, { cellNamespace: shapes });
const paper = new dia.Paper({ cellViewNamespace: shapes });
```

**Custom shapes**

If you define your own shapes do not forget to add it to the namespace as well *(this also apply for the custom views)*.

```js
const { standard, devs } = shapes;

// Custom Element Model
const MyRectangle = standard.Rectangle.define('myNamespace.Rectangle', {
  size: { width: 100, height: 100 },
  attrs: { body: { fill: 'red' }}
});

const graph = new dia.Graph({}, {
  cellNamespace: {
    // Optionally, cherry-pick namespaces/shapes you will use in your application
    standard,
    devs,
    myNamespace: { Rectangle: MyRectangle }
  }
});

const myRectangle = new MyRectangle();
myRectangle.addTo(graph);
const circle = new standard.Circle();
circle.addTo(graph);
```

Comment: good hint! after this post, I was able to find the necessary part in the docs. this is not very obvious and a very common issue when using jointjs with a build environment like webpack.

Answer (score 8):

I met a similar error saying 'markup required' just today when using jointjs with Vue. I followed the code and found that it is assuming 'joint' is present in global environment. So I add the following line in my code, and the error is gone:

```
import * as joint from 'jointjs'
window.joint = joint
```

Hopefully this helps.